# Is there a way to get live power usage

Tags: power

I'd like to monitor how much power is being used by my Mac.  The tools I've found so far either list the maximum power (85W for my laptop charger) or the processor's usage (Intel's Power Gadget).  I'd like a number that would be the same or close to what a Kill-a-watt meter would read.

Does a utility like that exist (preferably CLI)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) to read the sensor values, which include voltage, amperage, and wattage of various components in the system.

[image]

---

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/240561/118960

Comment: I use iStat, it's a great tool to monitor your Mac real-time.