# Macbook Pro Power Consumption

Tags: mac, power, activity-monitor

I was wondering if it is possible first of all to get the overall power consumption for my MacBook?

And if it is possible can I get this power consumption for each peripheral running (like consumption CPU, GPU, Wifi,...)?

Have checked the activity monitor, but nothing really interesting there, except for a very vague energy impact number.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) to read the sensor values, which include voltage, amperage and wattage of various components in the system.

[image]